# Going from black to green with limited input factor

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, math, colors

How can I make a method that takes in a float from 0-50, and gives out a green color with uniform intensity?

So if the input value is 0, the color is black:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0];
```

and if the input value is 50, the color is the max green color:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:0];
```

And so if the input factor is somewhere in the middle, then the color should be somewhere in the middle. So going from 0-50, it should go from the darkest green to the lightest green. Should be simple but I'm not sure what I'm missing:

```
//factor is a float from 0-50
UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:factor/255.0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
```

This code generates a green color, but doesn't fluctuate much, so you only see about one shade of green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scale the RGB max value (255) against your own max value (50). And all you need is fairly simple math:

```
colorVal = 255 * x / 50
```

where `x` is the intesity on the scale from 0 to 50. So:

```
255 * 0  / 50 = 0 
255 * 50 / 50 = 255
255 * 25 / 50 = 128 (rounded up from 127.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your range is only from `0.0/255.0 -> 50.0/255.0`, you want it to be `0.0 to 1.0`; for that you could try `factor/50.0`.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you're making the math too hard. Looks like the `[UIColor ... green: ...]` value is supposed to range from 0.0 to 1.0, so the value calculation could simply be:

```
CGFLoat value = factor / 50.0;
UIColor *greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:(value) blue:0 alpha:1]
```

That will give a value of 0.0 when `factor = 0` and 1.0 when `factor = 50`.

Beyond that, though, I'm not sure - maybe whatever actually does the drawing does some quantizing or works with a limited palette?

Comment: Ya I was way overcomplicating this :/